# Количество вхождений каждого символа С++

Tags: c++, строки

нужно подсчитать количество вхождения каждого символа. Например дана строка "Hello world"
Должно вывести (h,1),(e,1),(l,3) и так далее. ВАЖНО ! Нельзя использовать циклы. Можно сделать через vector. 
Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Берете `std::for_each` вместо цикла, и пишете как обычно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возьмите std::map и пробегитесь по строке,приэтом добовляя в нее новые литералы и инкрементируя их кол-во

Для удобвства вы можете поменять все регистры на нижний используя std::tolower если Вам это нужно!

Вот пример кода

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <locale>


int main() {

    std::string line{"Hello World"};
    std::map<char, int> m;
    std::map<unsigned char, int> m_lower;
    std::locale loc;

    auto f_obj_all_symb_to_lower{[&](char ch){ 
            if(!std::isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch))) {
                unsigned char to_add = std::tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch), loc);
                m_lower[to_add]++;
            }
        }
    };
    auto f_obj{[&](char ch){
            if(!std::isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch))) {
                m[ch]++;
            } 
        }
    };

    std::for_each(std::begin(line), std::end(line), f_obj);
    std::for_each(std::begin(line), std::end(line), f_obj_all_symb_to_lower);

    std::cout << "Real reg" << std::endl;
    for (const auto& var : m) {
        std::cout << "(" << var.first  << "," << var.second << ")" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "To lower" << std::endl;
    for (const auto& var : m_lower) {
        std::cout << "(" << var.first  << "," << var.second << ")" << std::endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::isspace(ch)` -> `std::isspace((unsigned char)ch)`, аналогично с `std::tolower`. А то будет UB на отрицательных кодах символов.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat upd

Answer (score 0):

Может кому-то нужно будет вот код:

```
std::string str = "Hello world";
std::map<char,int> myMap;
std::for_each(str.begin(),str.end(),[&myMap,&str](int i){
    myMap[str[i]]++;
});
```